# add one element into multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have a not difficult question, but I couldn't find an answer.

I have a multidimensional array for insert data with one query. The result is this:

```
INSERT INTO table (field1, field2, field3, field4) values ('1', '2', '3'),('1', '2', '3'),('1', '2', '3'),('1', '2', '3')
```

and I want to add one value in each tuple like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (field1, field2, field3, field4) values ('1', '2', '3','10'),('1', '2', '3','10'),('1', '2', '3','10'),('1', '2', '3','10')
```

This is the code (I also tried with array_push inside foreach):

```
$DataArr = array();
    for($i=1;$i<5;$i++){
        $fieldVal1 = 1;
        $fieldVal2 = 2;
        $fieldVal3 = 3;
 
        $DataArr[] = "('$fieldVal1', '$fieldVal2', '$fieldVal3')";
    }
$id=10;
$new=array();

foreach ($DataArr as $value) {
    $value[4]="'$id'";
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO table (field1, field2, field3) values ";
    $sql .= implode(',', $DataArr);
print_r($sql);
```

I tested this code but it doesn't work, can anyone help me?

Comment: Simple php function. Use `array_push($your_variable)`

Comment: @RobinSingh I have try with array_push($value,"'$id'"); but don't work

Comment: Please show your array structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Here is the easy solution

    $DataArr = array();
    for($i=1;$i<5;$i++){
        $fieldVal1 = 1;
        $fieldVal2 = 2;
        $fieldVal3 = 3;
        $DataArr[] = "('$fieldVal1', '$fieldVal2', '$fieldVal3')";
    }
    $id=10;
    $new=array();
    foreach ($DataArr as $key =>$value) {
        $tmpVal = ltrim($value,"(");
        $tmpVal = rtrim($tmpVal,")");
    
        $tmpArray = explode(',',$tmpVal);
        array_push($tmpArray,'4');
    
        array_push($new, "(".implode(',',$tmpArray).")");
         
    }
    
    
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table (field1, field2, field3, field4) values ";
    $sql .= implode(',', $new);
    print_r($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to set the imploded data to a variable to insert and then bind the param.

```
$DataArr = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
  $DataArr[$i] = "1,2,3";
}

$field1_arr = !empty($DataArr[0]) ? implode(",", $DataArr[0]) : "";
$field2_arr .= !empty($DataArr[1]) ? implode(",", $DataArr[1]) : "";
$field3_arr .= !empty($DataArr[2]) ? implode(",", $DataArr[2]) : "";
$field4_arr .= !empty($DataArr[3]) ? implode(",", $DataArr[3]) : "";;

$sql = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO table (field1, field2, field3, field4) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
$sql->bind_param("ssss", $field1_arr, $field2_arr, $field3_arr, $field4_arr);
if($sql->execute()) {
  // It worked
}
$sql->close();
```

Comment: basically I want to insert an array with a single insert into rather than doing a lot of queries with a foreach. I thought about creating this this dataarr which contains 3 of the 4 values, but I have to add the last attribute and do the insert into with mysqli.